# Is it possible to debug compiled .NET or C# with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, visual-studio-code

I have a an application that is using .NET framework 4.0.0.0. I don't have Visual Studio installed, at the moment nor do I have the source code for this application. I would like to debug it to find out why a specific feature of the application is failing. With Visual Studio, I could potentially attach the process and debug.

Instead, I installed Visual Studio Code. Is it possible to debug a .NET application with Visual Studio Code without having access to the source code? I read elsewhere that, for Visual Studio, if you have the PDB, you can do some debugging:

[how to debug anything with visual studio and jetbrains dotpeek v1.2](http://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/)

With dotPeek, you can start a symbol server and then have Visual Studio leverage that server, acting as the PDB file.

I do have JetBrains dotPeek v1.2 installed.

If I can't debug compiled code straight with Visual Studio Code and since I don't have the PDB, would it be possible to use dotPeek and Visual Studio Code, in concert? And, if so, how would I configure it?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Telerik's JustDecompile is free and can generate PDBs.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Even though it can generate PDB files, is it possible to use Visual Studio Code to debug compiled code, even with the PDB file? If so, I just am not sure how to set that up. Thank you.

Comment: I think VS code will only debug .Net Core apps.

Comment: You are correct. Says right on their website, that .Net Framework is not supported in VS Code. Even if the application was .NET Core, I'm not sure how to leverage PDB/symbol generation with VS Code or if it's even possible. Since the application is .NET Framework, VS Code won't help here and I have to use Visual Studio or something similar. Thanks again.